# Powershell HTML output not what is expected

Tags: powershell, html-email

Basically I'm just trying to output all of the BIOS information to a HTML table and email it to myself.

Specifically I'm just trying to return the output of:

```
get-wmiobject -class "Win32_BIOS" -namespace "root\CIMV2"
```

Into a table.  I've tried **convertto-html** but the output is all over the place, way to many columns (hard to describe and it wont translate very well on here).

what i have so far:

```
 function sendMail{
     $smtpServer = "server.com.au"
     $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
     $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
     $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
     $msg.From = "sender@server.com.au"
     $msg.To.Add("email@server.com.au")
     $msg.subject = "Subject"
     $msg.body = "$body"
     $smtp.Send($msg)  
}


$bios = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_BIOS" -namespace "root\CIMV2"
$body = $bios | ConvertTo-Html
sendmail
```

Though I have also tried **format-table** and a few other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graimer is correct. Trying to make that a table and put it into an email is just going to make a mess.  You can get it into an email as HTML in list format by doing this:

```
[string]$body = $bios | ConvertTo-Html -As List
```

But if you want a table you're going to have to pare it down to a reasonable number of columns to fit in an email.

Comment: A table is not really important, I should clarify that.  I basically just need it in a readable format.  EDIT:: Just tested and this is exactly what I was after, outputs into a readable format in the email.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How did you imagine it would be? What is the desired result? `ConvertTo-HTML` converts the object to an HTML page with tables. That means it includes EVERY property, which makes it messy since there are a lot of them (like WMI objects usually are). With `ConvertTo-HTML` property-names are headers, and values are in a row, so as you may see, ConvertTo-HTML is more suitable when outputting an array of items(which will result in many rows with single header-row.

If you only want to display some of the properties, you need to define it with `select-object` before using `ConvertTo-HTML`.

Another solution(depending on what you need) is just to use the output from the console instead of converting to html. Ex.

```
$bios = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_BIOS" -namespace "root\CIMV2"
$body = $bios | Out-String  
#You can use $bios | Format-List Your, Properties, Here | Out-String to specify different columns

$body

SMBIOSBIOSVersion : 3602
Manufacturer      : American Megatrends Inc.
Name              : 3602
SerialNumber      : System Serial Number
Version           : ALASKA - 1072009
```

Or

```
$body = $bios | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
#Again, you can specify columns with $bios| Format-Table -AutoSize My, Properties | Out-String

SMBIOSBIOSVersion Manufacturer             Name SerialNumber         Version         
----------------- ------------             ---- ------------         -------         
3602              American Megatrends Inc. 3602 System Serial Number ALASKA - 1072009
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, still not what I was expecting, both of these  output correctly (formatting) in the console, but when sent in the email it is all run together on a single line.

Comment: Did you try it with $msg.IsBodyHtml = $false? (default value) My solutions with Out-String aren't html code.